# JPQL - update foreign key id without unnecessary selects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following database schema:

```
create table country (
  id integer primary key
);

create table city (
  id integer primary key, 
  country_id integer references country
);
```

and mappings:

```
@Entity
class Country {
    @Id private Integer id;
    ...
}

@Entity
class City {
    @Id private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne private Country country;
    ...
}
```

Now I have `countryId` and `cityId`. I need to update table city and change it's country. I would do in SQL something like that: `update city set country_id = :countryId where id = :cityId`.

I can update simple properties with JPQL with similar syntax. But how can I update foreign key reference in the example above?

Of course I can get corresponding entities by id and update java entities, something like

```
City city = em.find(cityId, City.class);
Country country = em.find(countryId, Country.class);
city.setCountry(country);
```

but this code will issue 2 unnecessary selects. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: For JPA and Hibernate check Vlad Mihalcea: https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the EntityManager.getReference() method exists just for this purpose.
See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you're using @Query annotation for example.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. It seems to be simple enough. Just create new entity object, initialize its id and pass it as a parameter to JPQL update query:

```
Country country = new Country();
country.setId(countryId);
Query query = em.createQuery("update City set country = :country where id = :cityId");
query.setParameter("country", country);
query.setParameter("cityId", cityId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Apparently JPA doesn't care whether that `country` object was retrieved from database or created manually, only `id` property must be set.